# Unity 3D not able to change resolution in windowed mode on windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I'm creating an option menu to be able to change resolution and switch fullscreen/windowed mode.
When I'm in windowed, after the change in resolution takes place, the Screen.currentResolution property still contains 1920x1080. 
I'm not able to change that value using Screen.SetResolution().
In fullscreen mode everything works fine.
I don't have any idea how to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: I see in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html): "A resolution switch does not happen immediately; it will actually happen when the current frame is finished."

Comment: Thanks, but Screen.currentResolution remains the same also after I changed the scene.

Comment: I think we need more information from you. Read [this](http://www.aclockworkberry.com/managing-screen-resolution-and-aspect-ratio-in-unity-3d/) and [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1453350/screencurrentresolution-values-dont-change-after-s.html) item; maybe it fits in your case.

Comment: If you want to check how something would work on different resolutions the easiest way for the editor is to switch to android platform. Now you are able to change the resolution of the game window and you can add own resolutions!

Comment: I tried to print the resolution of the game viewport while in windowed mode using the OnGui() methods. 
I found that after 2 calls of the method OnGui() the resolution is changed to 1920x1080. 
Ex:
I set the resolution to 720x480 while in windowed mode. (Resize of the window works fine). I press the back button to return to the main menu, everythings fine. Reentering the options menu will trigger the reset of the resolution. During start() the resolution is still 720x480, after 2 calls of OnGui (which just print the resolution) the resolution gets changed to 1920x1080.